# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Exception while sending data yo View through viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

When i am trying to run the view it is giving the above exception in this line

```
@model ClothBazar.Web.ViewModels.HomeViewModels
```

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
var firstCategory = Model.Categories.Where(x => x.ImageURL != null).First(); //it is fetching null value in firstcategory
}

While i have data in my table already
[image]

Code from HomeViewModels class

```
    public class HomeViewModels
{
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Code of Category Class

```
    public class Category : BaseEntities
{
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Home Index Action

```
  CategoryService categoryService = new CategoryService();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HomeViewModels model = new HomeViewModels();
        model.Categories = categoryService.GetCategories();
        return View();
    }
```

Not able to figure out why var firstCategory is not picking up any value

Comment: Please share `Action` method from where you assign `Model`.

Comment: i have added the action method

Comment: Thankyou so much Karan i got the error it was in action method i forgot to pass the model in view .

Answer (score 0):

As seeing your code, you need update your code section. on the View page you are accessing your `HomeViewModels` which is ViewModel. So if you want to get the `Categories` value you made loop through on it because it's list type.

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";     
Foreach(var category in Model.Categories ) 
{
   //Access your value inside this or bind you html code here
}    
}
```

I hope this direction will help you.

Comment: when i am storing the value of category in var firstCategory inside forloop how will i use that variable outsite ?                                                                                                   
 foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
    {
        if(category.ImageURL != null)
        {
            var firstCategory  = category;

        }
    }

Comment: Thanks for the help aswal

Answer (score 0):

The error was in action method

```
     CategoryService categoryService = new CategoryService();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HomeViewModels model = new HomeViewModels();
        model.Categories = categoryService.GetCategories();
        return View(model);
    }
```